# I cannot open an IP address in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, home-networking, ip, ip-address, dsl

I have installed some cameras in my private business and now I wanted to open the views from my computer. I got the Ip address and the username along with the password. However when I tried to open it from my desktop computer, i couldn't. I used Firefox and Chromium but both of them say :"problem loading the page" or something similar. What should I do?

Comment: You need to provide **more** information. How are the cameras connected to the network? What does your network setup look like? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you cannot connect to the cameras while you are in the same building, connected to the same Local Area Network?  Or do you mean that when you go home, you cannot connect to the cameras from your home computer?  Because the solutions would be different.

If you cannot connect to the cameras from a computer on the same LAN, then it is probably just a matter of adding the proper port to the end of the IP address.  For example... if the camera is getting an internal IP address of 192.168.1.100 and it operates on port 8181, then you would try to view http://192.168.1.100:8181

If you are trying to connect to the cameras at your business and you are at home, and you have the IP address of your business connection, then you would have first had to forward the port in the settings of your router at work, to have the port linked to that specific internal IP address.  Your business might have it's own IP address... like http://24.57.119.81 or whatever... but that is the IP address that is assigned to everything that is going on at your business.  If you have the modem at your business connected to a router so that multiple computers can all get online, then the router is assigning an internal IP address to each device that is connected to it, and that internal IP address is different from that external IP address.  If each camera is attached to the router, then each camera is getting an internal IP address like 192.168.1.100 or what-have-you.  Mind you, each camera would have a DIFFERENT address.  Now, if you want to be able to view each camera, you would have to be able to assign each a different port to be viewed at, and then you would have to go into the admin settings of the router, and enter the port forwarding section.  There, you could assign the camera ports to the specific internal IP addresses that each camera was getting.

Then, when you connected to that external IP address your business has, and you added the proper port following a colon, you could view each camera.

Otherwise, you just haven't supplied enough specific information regarding your setup to be able to diagnose your issue.